# Using the Euclidean algorithm in a field extension to find an inverse

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, euclidean-algorithm

In a course on Galois theory which I'm taking, the following example problem has come up.

Let $\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{\mathbb{Q}[x]f} = \mathbb{Q}(t)$ be a field where $f = t^3 -2 = 0$. Find the inverse of $t^2 + 1$ in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$.

The solution given to this example problem starts by saying:

*"The Euclidean algorithm gives $5 = (x^2+1)(-x^2+2x+1)+(x^3-2)(x-2)$"*

I understand the structure of the field, and I understand the problem. I thought I had an understanding of how the Euclidean algorithm works, but I don't understand how we have arrived at this answer.

I can see that if $g = t^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{Q}(t)$, then $g$ and $f$ are coprime, so we have $1 = rg + sf$ for some $r,s$. That's about as far as I got.

EDIT:

To be clear, I'm not asking why this is the answer. I'm asking how we got there in the first place, via the Euclidean algorithm. How does the Euclidean algorithm give the above?

Comment: Don't confuse $x$ with $t$. $f=x^3-2,$ $f(t)=t^3-2=0$.

Comment: It will take some time to type, but this is the extended euclidean algorithm for finding the gcd of $x^2 + 1, x^3 - 2,$ confirming that the gcd is $1,$ more precisely any unit in the ring (meaning nonzero constant), and giving the coefficients. It really is mechanical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$$rg+sf=1$$
in $\mathbb{Q}\left(x\right)$, then
$$\overline{r}\cdot\overline{g}+\overline{s}\cdot\overline{f}=\overline{1}$$
in $\mathbb{Q}\left(x\right)/f\mathbb{Q}\left(x\right)$, where $\overline{h}=h+f\mathbb{Q}\left(x\right)$. Since $\overline{f}=\overline{0}$, we have
$$\overline{r}\cdot\overline{g}=\overline{1}$$
which means that $\overline{r}$ is the inverse of $\overline{g}$, as required.

Comment: This makes sense to me. I understand why the given answer is true, I just don't understand how we got there via the Euclidean algorithm. Should I edit the question to make it clearer what I'm asking?

Comment: No need for now. When you talk about the Euclidean algorithm, do you mean the algorithm of finding the gcd of two numbers / polynomials, or also the coefficients of their linear combination which gives the gcd?

Comment: I suppose I mean either, although in this case above I am talking about using it to find the coefficients of their linear combination (which I think is what is being suggested in the given solution to the example).

Comment: @MattS Then let's apply the Euclidean algorithm on $f=x^3-2$ and $g=x^2+1$. We have $\left(x^3-2,x^2+1\right)=\left\{x^3-2=x\left(x^2+1\right)-x-2\right\}=$
$=\left(x^2+1,-x-2\right)=\left\{x^2+1=\left(-x+2\right)\left(-x-2\right)+5\right\}=\left(-x-2,5\right)=1$.

Hence
$$5=x^2+1-\left(-x+2\right)\left(-x-2\right)=x^2+1-\left(-x+2\right)\left(x^3-2-x\left(x^2+1\right)\right)$$
Simplify the expression to get the desired equality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the calculation, maybe I will typeset the good part later, the fractions $p_j/q_j$

$$  
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 & & x & & -x+2 & & (-x-2)/5 &   \\
\frac{0}{1} & \frac{1}{0} & & \frac{x}{1} &  &  \frac{-x^2 + 2x + 1}{-x+2} & &  \frac{\frac{x^3 - 2}{5}}{\frac{x^2 +1}{5}}    
\end{array}
$$
This is the continued fractions style of writing that I like, easy to remember. The litle two by two cross product of consecutive "fractions" is $\pm 1$
These are
$$ 0 \cdot 0 - 1 \cdot 1 = -1 $$
$$ 1 \cdot 1 - x \cdot 0 = 1 $$
$$ x \cdot (-x+2) - (-x^2+2x+1) \cdot -1 = 1 $$
$$ (-x^2+2x+1) \cdot \left(\frac{x^2 +1}{5}\right) - \left(\frac{x^3 - 2}{5}\right) \cdot (-x+2) = -1 $$
Mukltiply the last one through by $5$ and you have the identity you asked about.

```
parisize = 4000000, primelimit = 500509
? f0 = x^3 - 2
%1 = x^3 - 2
? f1 = x^2 + 1
%2 = x^2 + 1
? 
? d2 = x
%3 = x
? f2 = f0 - d2 * f1
%4 = -x - 2
? 
? d3 = -x + 2
%5 = -x + 2
? f3 = f1 - d3 * f2
%6 = 5
? 
? d4 = f2 / f3 
%7 = -1/5*x - 2/5
? f4 = f2 - d4 * f3
%8 = 0
? 
? 
? p0 = 0
%9 = 0
? q0 = 1
%10 = 1
? 
? p1 = 1
%11 = 1
? q1 = 0
%12 = 0
? 
? p2 = d2 * p1 + p0
%13 = x
? q2 = d2 * q1 + q0
%14 = 1
? 
? p3 = d3 * p2 + p1
%15 = -x^2 + 2*x + 1
? q3 = d3 * q2 + q1
%16 = -x + 2
? 
? p4 = d4 * p3 + p2
%17 = 1/5*x^3 - 2/5
? q4 = d4 * q3 + q2
%18 = 1/5*x^2 + 1/5
? 
?
```